# Rails rake db:migrate aborted on a read-only mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, migration, rake

I have a problem when working with Rails' `rake db:migrate`. I want a connection to an existing external MySQL database, and have configured my `database.yml` into this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  adapter: mysql
  host: [my_host]
  username: [my_user]
  password: [my_pass]
  database: [my_db]

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Then I shut down the Rails' server and ran `rails server` again to see if my connection goes well. I'm still working locally, in development mode. However, I got `ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError`. Trying to follow the advice, the process was aborted instead. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1f1z.png) is the snapshot.

And the trace.

```
Mac-User:rails-test user$ bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement: CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations` (`version` varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `query'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `block in execute'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `execute'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:205:in `create_table'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:460:in `create_table'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:29:in `create_table'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:656:in `initialize_schema_migrations_table'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:918:in `initialize'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `new'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Mysql::Error: The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `query'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `block in execute'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:373:in `block in log'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:367:in `log'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:303:in `execute'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:205:in `create_table'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:460:in `create_table'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:29:in `create_table'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:656:in `initialize_schema_migrations_table'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:918:in `initialize'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `new'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/Users/ruma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My concern is the command was going to do some `CREATE TABLE` while the external database is read-only. Can anyone figure out how to pass or skip the `db:migrate`? I'm not going to update any single thing on the database anyway.

Your respond will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: look into one of the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244244/rails-4-how-to-ignore-pending-migrations

Comment: okay, thanks a lot for the link @jvnill ! will dive into this.

Comment: hey @jvnill, it seems one of the answers is a magic for me. If you want, please write your answer as comment, and I'll accept and upvote for you :)

Comment: no need, i really think this is a duplicate of that question i linked to so this question should really be closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4 how to ignore pending migrations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244244/rails-4-how-to-ignore-pending-migrations)