# Ruby on Rails with external database, issues with web requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-migrations

I need to use Ruby on Rails with an external Postgres database. I have hooked up models to the database, and can run searches to the database using calls like Model.all. However, when I try and do a web request of the same data, I get the following error:

```
Started GET "/v1/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-19 22:53:34 -0800

ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError (

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

    bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

):
```

I am an amateur Rails and database user, so I'm not sure what exactly a migrate does, but I do not have write permissions, so I cannot run one.

So, what can I do to the Rails project such that I can complete these web requests without needing to perform a migration? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to run the migrations (and you don't, if your external database is already set up with the schema you need), then simply delete them from your `db/migrate` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Here is also a link to how to a couple of approaches:

[Rails 4 how to ignore pending migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244244/rails-4-how-to-ignore-pending-migrations)

This will mean you can keep your migrations, in case you ever need to use them somewhere else.

Basic approaches described:

- setting a version number
- turning off the error with:

  config.active_record.migration_error = false